# How to hook into protobuf java code generation?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protoc, protobuf-java

Is there any way to hook into the generation of java classes when invoking `protoc`? I know there are plugins which can be created for protoc but as far as I understood it is only possible to generate additional files there. What I would like to do is adding additional code into the java classes based on some options in the protobuf schemas.

So for the following schema:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

enum DateFormat {
  LOCAL_DATE = 0;
  LOCAL_DATE_TIME = 1;
}

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions  {
  DateFormat format = 95765;
}

message MyMessage {
  string name = 1;
  sint64 id = 2;
  string dateTimeField = 3 [(format) = LOCAL_DATE_TIME];
}
```

I would like to have the `dateTimeField` in the generated java class of type `LocalDateTime` which contains the already parsed date time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this. Plugins can not only create new files, but also use insertion points to extend classes generated by the java code generator, see https://protobuf.dev/reference/java/java-generated/#plugins.

There is a great [article](https://medium.com/urbanmatrix-technologies/the-missing-guide-to-protobuf-insertion-points-in-java-kotlin-2f1b2bb183db) which describes exactly how to create a plugin which uses those insertion points.